# Compound index by array in mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongodb collection where documents contain the following fields (documents have a lot of fields but I removed them for understanding):

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("53aad11444d0e2fd648b4567"),
   "id": NumberLong(238790),
   "rid": NumberLong(12),
   "parent_id": {
        "0": NumberLong(12),
        "1": NumberLong(2) 
    },
   "coid": NumberLong(3159),
   "reid": NumberLong(4312),
   "cid": NumberLong(4400) 
}
```

When I run a query I get

```
> db.ads2.find({coid:3159, parent_id : 2}).sort({inserdate:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor coid_1_parent_id_1_insertdate_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 20444,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20444,
    "nscanned" : 20444,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 20444,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 20444,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 319,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 274,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "coid" : [
            [
                3159,
                3159
            ]
        ],
        "parent_id" : [
            [
                2,
                2
            ]
        ],
        "insertdate" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myserver.com:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

The question is how should I change the index to make mongo to use it properly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query and the document structure you posted do not match. If you run this query on the collection that contains documents with that kind of structure you will get no results.

But since your query yielded `20444` results I guess that your structure actually looks like this:

```
{
   ...
   "parent_id": [
        "0": NumberLong(12),
        "1": NumberLong(2) 
    ],
    ...
}
```

This is the index you created:

```
   db.x.ensureIndex({coid : 1, parent_id : 1, insertdate : -1});
```

From your `explain()` output you can see that MongoDB is using index to find the documents (because number of scanned documents is equal to the number of returned documents `n == nscanned`). But, `"scanAndOrder" : true` means that MongoDB is not using the index to sort your documents.

Your index should be used for matching and sorting *if* the field you're using to sort exist in the documents.

But the problem is that I can't see `insertdate` field nowhere in your structure. So if you're sorting by a field that doesn't exist in your document, normally, MongoDB can't use the index for sorting.

**Edit**

After your comment and examination of your original question I probably found what's causing your problem. You have a typo in the query you're executing. You're specifying the sort parameter as `inserdate`, while the name of the field that was indexes is `insertdate`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I forgot to add the fields "inserdate" to the structure in example. Actually it is  there in the real structure.

So how I can understand in case of a long time query mongo uses the index but it should scan more indexes that wasting more time.

Comment: @RoSh you should update your question with the correct structure so that it's more clear for others reading your question.